# How can I delete the PS Plus games of the month after my PS Plus subscription ended?

Tags: ps4

I subscribed to PS Plus for two months and decided it was not for me. I downloaded all the games of the month then realized I don't want to actually play them anymore. Whenever I try downloading a new game, I don't have enough storage, and I don't want to spend money on more subscriptions for more storage on my PS4. I have already tried uninstalling the games, but when I check in the store, the only options I get are to like the game or buy it. Please help me

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to uninstall games, but the PS Store is not one of them.

#### From the home screen (if you want to uninstall only one or two games)

1. Go to the home screen and navigate to the game you want to uninstall. The home screen is the screen where you launch games or access the PS Store.
   [image: Screenshot of home screen]
2. Instead of pressing <kbd>X</kbd> to launch the game, press <kbd>OPTIONS</kbd>. This will open a side menu where you can choose "Delete", which is the second to last option.
   [image: Screenshot of OPTIONS menu]
3. Confirm by selecting "OK".
   [image: Screenshot of confirmation screen]

#### From the Settings (if you want to uninstall many games at once)

1. Open the Settings. The Settings is in the top bar on the Home screen. You can access the top bar by pressing "Up" on the D-Pad. The Settings is the second item from the right.
   [image: Screenshot of top bar]
2. Scroll down until you see "Storage" and select it. If an application is currently running, you will need to close it.
   [image: Screenshot of Settings]
3. Select "System Storage", or whichever storage the game is installed in, if you're using an external USB storage device. You can select the storage device even while it says "Calculating..."
   [image: Screenshot of Storage screen]
4. Select "Applications". You will need to wait until the PS4 has finished "Calculating..."
   [image: Screenshot of System Storage screen]
5. Press <kbd>OPTIONS</kbd> and choose "Delete". This will enable the delete mode.
   [image: Screenshot of OPTIONS menu]
6. Select all the games you want to uninstall, then choose "Delete".
   [image: Screenshot of delete mode]
7. Confirm by selecting "OK".
   [image: Screenshot of confirmation screen]